# The image of any open interval containing the origin by $\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ is $[-1,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

EDIT: Before the answer of Kavi Rama Murthy the word open wasn't in the title nor in the question's body.

Define the function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x)=\begin{cases} \sin \left( \dfrac{1}{x} \right), x \neq 0 \\ 0, x=0\end{cases}$

I already proved that $f$ is discontinuous, because the limit as $x \to 0$ doesn't exist. But how do I prove that the image of any open interval $I$ such that $0 \in I$ is $[-1,1]$?

Looking at the graph it seems true, but I'd like a proof.

It's clear that $f(I) \subseteq [-1,1]$, because $\sin(y) \in [-1,1] \forall y$, but given $x \in [-1,1]$, how do I prove $x \in f(I)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image of any **open** interval containing $0$ is $[-1,1]$. (If the word 'open' is omitted then $I$ could be $\{0\}$ so the result is false).

Now observe that $f(\frac1 {2n\pi +\frac {\pi} 2})=1$ and $f(\frac1 {2n\pi +\frac {3\pi} 2})=-1$. Hence the image of $(-\epsilon, \epsilon)$ contains both $1$ and $-1$ for any $\epsilon >0$.  Since $f$ is continuous on $(0,\epsilon)$ we can use IVP to conclude that $f((0,\epsilon))$ contains all points between $-1$ and $+1$.